# Replacing a string inside a txt line by line

Tags: c

How would i check for the strings below **line by line in a txt** and replace each one?

```
"FLD_CUSTORDREF_FLD"                 
"FLD_CUSTOMERNAME_FLD"            
"FLD_ADDRESSLINE1_FLD"             
"FLD_ADDRESSLINE2_FLD"             
"FLD_CITY_FLD"
```

e.g.

```
If file line has "FLD_CITY_FLD"
  change to Header->City
else if file line has "FLD_CUSTOMERNAME_FLD" 
  change to Header->Name
```

I can read each line by using

```
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL )
```

But how would i check for a matching string?

Comment: Does it have to be with C?  Using Perl, Awk, Ruby, Python, etc. would be much simpler.

Comment: Amen to that - this has to either be homework or a shining example of inappropriate choice of tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `strstr` function.

> ```
> char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
> ```
>
> The `strstr()` function finds the first occurrence of the substring
>   needle in the string haystack.

However the replacing part might be trickier. I would just `fprintf` the result instead of replacing in the string.